# Regex - Match attribute in a HTML code

Tags: html, regex

I have problem with matching the html attributes **(in a various html tags)** with regex. To do so, I use the pattern:

```
myAttr=\"([^']*)\"
```

HTML snippet:

```
<img alt="" src="1-p2.jpg" myAttr="http://example.com" class="alignleft" />
```

it selects text from the `myAttr` the end `/>` but I need to select the `myAttr="..."` ("http://example.com")

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have an apostrophe (`'`) inside your character class but you wanted a quote (`"`).

```
myAttr=\"([^"]*)\"
```

That said, you really [shouldn't be parsing HTML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  (Sorry to link to **that** answer again. There are other answers to that question that are more of the "if you know what you are doing..." variety.  But it is good to be aware of.)

Note that even if you limit your regexing to just attributes you have a lot to consider:

- Be careful not to match inside of comments.
- Be careful not to match inside of CDATA sections.
- What if attributes are bracketed with single quotes instead of double quotes?
- What if attributes have no quotes at all?

This is why pre-built, serious parsers are generally called for.

Comment: if the attribute value contain \"   ,this regex will be wrong  such as <a href="dddd"  c="\"abc\""/>

Comment: Nice, another good reason not to use regexes here! It is completely the wrong approach.

Answer (score 10):

The * is a greedy quantifier. You should follow it with a question mark to make it non-greedy:

```
myAttr=\"([^']*?)\"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the myAttr parameter *value*, use this:

```
"myAttr=\"([^\"]+)\""
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try use that

```
 myAttr=\"?[\w:\-]+ ?= ?("[^"]+"|'[^']+'|\w+)\"
```

Answer (score -5):

<[^>]*>

Just try this is this help for remove all tag

Example

Something

Comment: Did you read the question?