# Image Tag's src by using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find the first **img tag's src** by using **regex** to the following string.
How to do that ?

```
>&lt;div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on"&gt;&lt;div class="MsoNormal"
 style="background: white; line-height: 15.0pt; margin-bottom: .0001pt; margin-bottom: 0in; mso-outline-level: 2; vertical-align: baseline;"&gt;&lt;div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-c-ugY7XUnYo/UoJtj0dzvKI/AAAAAAAAACA/qWtvYnP9wfc/s1600/Screen+shot+2013-11-12+at+10.03.25+AM.png" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"&gt;&lt;img border="0" height="257" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-c-ugY7XUnYo/UoJtj0dzvKI/AAAAAAAAACA/qWtvYnP9wfc/s320/Screen+shot+2013-11-12+at+10.03.25+AM.png" width="320" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;h4&gt;&lt;span style="background-color: transparent;"&gt;With over 150,000 pet care professionals in the United States, your ability to differentiate your business is critical to long-term sustainable growth.&amp;nbsp; By focusing on the customer experience you can gain the loyalty of prospective pet parents and continue to thrive with your current pack.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style="background-color: transparent;"&gt;&amp;nbsp; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style="background-color: transparent;"&gt;Below are 5 ways to differentiate your pet business so you have a leg up on your local competitors.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h4&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="MsoNormal"&gt;&lt;div
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671925/regex-match-attribute-in-a-html-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>

string src = Regex.Match(original_text, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

## [Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/6kFmkIidgh)

Comment: You have to escape < and > by backslashs, so instead of "<" you have to put "\\<".

Comment: Fantastic.It's working.I also would like to learn Regex like you.Could you tell me where should I start from ? Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Don't use Regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/932418). Use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

```
var html = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(yourtext);
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var urls = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]")
              .Select(img => img.Attributes["src"].Value)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: I agree not to parse html using Regex. But in this simple case Regex can be just handy and practical.