# RegEx for matching between any two HTML tags

Tags: java, regex, pcre, regex-greedy, replaceall

I have the following content :

```html
<div class="TEST-TEXT">hi</span>
<a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST-TEXT\">first young CEO's TEST-TEXT</a>
<span class="test">hello</span>
```

I am trying to match the TEST-TEXT string to replace it is value but only when it is a text and not within an attribute value.

I have checked the concepts of look-ahead and look-behind in Regex but the current issue with that is that it needs to use a fixed width for the match here is a link [regex-match-all-characters-between-two-html-tags](https://ntam.me/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-html-tags/) that show case a very similar case but with an exception that there is a span with a class to create a match
also checked the link [regex-match-attribute-in-a-html-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671925/regex-match-attribute-in-a-html-code)

here are two regular expressions I am trying with :

> 1. \"([^"]*)\"
> 2. (?s)(?<=<([^{]*)>)(.+?)(?=</.>)

both are not working for me try using [https://regex101.com/r/ApbUEW/2]

I expect it to match only the string when it is a text 
current behavior it matches both cases

Edit : I want the text to be dynamic and not specific to TEST-TEXT

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Regex isn't powerful enough to parse HTML https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @TheScientificMethod to match the third TEST-TEXT which is when it is a inner text of two tags

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Kumar Rajwanshi what else would you suggest to use ?

Comment: try: `TEST-TEXT(?=<\/a>)`

Comment: Usually when we want to work on HTML we use HTML *parser*. IMO https://jsoup.org/ is quite easy and yet powerful because of CSS queries selectors. See https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: @Pshemo yes I use this library but in this case it didn't server the required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RegEx for that a string between any two HTML tags

`(?![^<>]*>)(TEST\-TEXT)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
\>([^"<]*)\<
```

EDIT:

Without open and close tags included:

```
(?<=\>)([^"<]*)(?=\<)
```

Comment: that would also include the opining and closing tag I want it to only match the string inside.

Comment: that would match any text in between tags, I want it to match a specific string

Answer (score 0):

Try `TEST-TEXT(?=<\/a>)`

`TEST-TEXT` matches TEST-TEXT

`?=` look ahead to check closing tag `</a>`

see at
[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ApbUEW/1)

Comment: TEST-TEXT(?=<\/.*>) that would match all tags but I still want the text to be dynamic

Comment: to make it dynamic,  use `TEST-TEXT(?=<\.*>)`

Comment: that wont match anything

Answer (score 0):

Here, we might just add a soft boundary on the right of the desired output, which you have been already doing, then a char list for the desired output, then collect, after that we can make a replacement by using capturing groups `()`. Maybe similar to this:

```
([A-Z-]+)(<\/)
```

[image]

#### Demo

This snippet is just to show that the expression might be valid:

```js
const regex = /([A-Z-]+)(<\/)/gm;
const str = `<div class="TEST-TEXT">hi</span><a href=\\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST-TEXT\\">first young CEO's
TEST-TEXT</a><span class="test">hello</span><div class="TEST-TEXT">hi</span><a href=\\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST-TEXT\\">first young CEO's
TEST-TEXT</a><span class="test">hello</span>`;
const subst = `NEW-TEXT$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MOVmk7/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

Comment: that will only work when there is a closing tag after the sting what I am looking for is a match for the string in all cases when it is a text and not an attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

```
      String html = "<div class=\"TEST-TEXT\">hi</span>\n" +
            "<a href=\\\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST-TEXT\\\">first young CEO's TEST-TEXT</a>\n" +
            "<span class=\"test\">hello</span>";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<)(.*)(>)(.*)(TEST-TEXT)(.*)</.*>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
    while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
    }
```

Comment: that will only match it if it is the only string between the two tags.